# How can I see my skill abilities?

Tags: the-secret-world

I've just started playing The Secret World. In the game you have room to place skill points and ability points. It seems that if you place a skill point you get a small passive bonus. But it went away too fast and I didn't actually see what bonus I got. Is there a way for me to see what the future skills give, and what the previous skills have given me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand the particular skill bar in question (hit the +) and mouse over the little tick marks instead of the button to allocate skill points.  It'll display what the current tier gives you, and also what the next tier will give you (at the low levels I've hit, always just seems to be a slightly upgraded version of the same effect).

Comment: Hmm, very strange i was doing that 2 days ago but it didn't work, tried yesterday and it did work. Thanks!

Comment: I've noticed occasionally that tooltips in this game will misbehave (often in mission results screens, oddly enough).  Probably just some bugs to work out!